# custom domain mapping to subdomains

Tags: domain-mapping

I have searched and have not been able to find anything helpful.

I have a mydomain.com that is setup to allow wildcard subdomains (*.mydomain.com).

I need to be able to have clientdomain.com point to clientdomain.mydomain.com.

I've setup a CNAME clientdomain.com > clientdomain.mydomain.com, though I get the standard CPANEL error page since clientdomain.com is not configured on that host.

I need to be able to do this on the fly - so I cannot ad a hostrecord for each domain, unless there is a way to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

CNAME record will not work as the parent and source domains are not hosted on the same server.

You will have to the redirection feature in cpanel to get this task done by creating proper subdomain. You can set the redirection through redirection option in cpanel.

Comment: I don't want to add in each domain manually - i need to automate the process